# How do I unpack the values of a tuple in a dictionary comprehension without creating any new variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, tuples, dictionary-comprehension

I have a tuple that contains multiple sub tuples, with a fixed length of two and each sub tuple has two string values.

**NOTE:** The length and value type of these sub tuples never change.

I'd like to use the sub tuples in a dictionary-comprehension, like this:

```
{sub_tuple for sub_tuple in main_tuple}
```

The problem is, I get:

```
{(w, x), (y, z)}
```

Instead of:

```
{w: x, y: z}
```

How can I get this to work without creating any additional variables?

For example, how do I avoid doing something like this:

```
x = {}
for sub_tuple in main_tuple:
  x[sub_tuple[0]] = sub_tuple[1]
# do whatever with x...
```

Comment: The dupe "reverses" the order - but you should be able to derive your solution from it as well. Those answers duplicate the ones give here "with an added twist".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
x = {
    key: value
    for key, value in main_tuple
}
```

Even simpler, you could do `x = dict(main_tuple)`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the dict constructor instead:

```
dict(main_tuple)
```